# O que é o operador "^" no Bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

```
i=1
aux=3
aux=$(($aux^$i))
echo $aux
#2
```

Alguém pode me explicar este código?

Comment: Quando se digita `$(( ))` você está entrando em um "ambiente matemático" especial. Possivelmente o `^` esteja fazendo a operação `XOR`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^` é o operador "ou exclusivo" ([*bitwise XOR*](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ops.html)). Basicamente, ele pega a representação binária dos números envolvidos e aplica as seguintes regras, bit a bit:

- se ambos os bits forem iguais (ambos forem 0 ou ambos forem 1), o resultado é 0
- senão, o resultado é 1

Então ao fazer `3 ^ 1`, temos:

```
00000011  <- 3 em binário
00000001  <- 1 em binário
--------
00000010  <- 2 em binário
```

Nas 6 primeiras posições, os bits são todos zero, então o resultado dessas posições será zero. Na sétima posição, o primeiro bit é 1 e o outro é zero, então o resultado, segundo as regras acima, é 1. E na oitava posição, ambos são 1, então o resultado é zero.

O resultado final é a representação binária do número 2.

---

A expressão deve estar entre `(( ))`, já que esta é a [construção que permite executar operações aritméticas](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html).

O `$` é colocado na frente dos parênteses para que o resultado da expressão seja atribuído à variável (`aux=$(($aux^$i))`). Mas também poderia ser feito assim:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
aux=3
((aux = $aux^$i))
echo $aux
```

<sup>*[Veja aqui](https://ideone.com/oiXUQr) o código rodando*</sup>

Comment: Entendi, mas no caso ainda continuei com a seguinte dúvida:  Dado um determinado array pede-se para mostrar os elementos que "ocorrem apenas uma vez". Como que este mecanismo funciona possibilitando isto, já que a comparação ocorre entre dois números? https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/lonely-integer/problem

Comment: read num
read arr
aux=0
for i in $arr;
    do
      
        aux=$(($aux^$i))
       
    done

echo $aux

Comment: @BrunoSouto Não sei se é isso que vc quer saber, mas talvez ajude (veja o método 4): https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-two-repeating-elements-in-a-given-array/

Comment: @BrunoSouto Na verdade acho que é isso (veja o método 3): https://codepumpkin.com/find-unique-array-element/#XORApproach